# `For x in locals():` -- RuntimeError: Why does locals() change size?

Tags: python, iteration

I have a function and want to get the arguments passed to it. I tried achieving this via `locals()`, but I end up getting the keys of `locals()`, not the value-pairs:

```
>>>def print_params(i,j,k):
    for x in locals():
        print(x)
>>>print_params('a','b','c')
j
i
k     #<--I want to get back 'a','b','c'.
```

I'd like to get the values instead of the keys, from `locals()`.

With a normal dict, I know I can do this:

```
>>> m = {
... 'a' : 'b',
... 'y' : 'z'}
>>> m
{'a': 'b', 'y': 'z'}
>>> for x in m:
...     print(x)
...
a      # <--Keys
y
>>> for x in m:
...     print(m[x])
...
b      # <--Values
z
```

But, if I try this with `locals()`, it creates a RuntimeError.

```
>>> def print_args(i,j,k):
...     for x in locals():
...         print(locals()[x])
...
>>> print_args('a','b','c')
b                          # <--Got one!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in y
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

Can someone explain what's happening? From the single value I got to print (before it errors out), I can see that the error arises when the loop attempts to iterate to the next element of `locals()`; then, as the dict has been modified, it loses its place. I can't make sense of why the dictionary size should change, though. I'm inferring that, on each pass through the `for` loop, the variable `x` is destroyed, then re-created for the next pass through the loop. However, this seems odd, since I would think it'd be more efficient to keep `x` "alive" and just re-assign it to the new value on each iteration.

Ultimately, I guess I could just do `local_args = locals()`, but I'm still curious as to what exactly is happening that prevents me from simply looping through `locals()`. I'm not sure if I'm right about `x` being destroyed/recreated; if I am, I have to wonder why that is, and if I'm not, then I'm even more curious as to what's happening.

Comment: Because `x` is a new variable: it is therefore a new item in the dictionary of local variables.

Comment: "But, if I try this with `locals()`" No, you've tried something subtly different.

Comment: You're not supposed to use `locals()`. Why can't your function be `def print_params(*i):` and then `for x in i: print(x)` or just `print(*i)`? It would even retain the original order of the arguments as you passed them in.

Comment: Also, you probably want to iterate over `locals().values()`, since you want the values and not the keys. Or maybe even `locals().items()` to get both.

Comment: Didn't even think about using `.values()`. That's a good solution. So is using the `*i`; I had to look that one up because I'd never seen it before, but I think that's a pretty cool feature of the language. Didn't know it existed, to be honest, but now that I do, I'll use it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can someone explain what's happening? From the single value I got to print (before it errors out), I can see that the error arises when the loop attempts to iterate to the next element of locals(); then, as the dict has been modified, it loses its place. I can't make sense of why the dictionary size should change, though. I'm inferring that, on each pass through the for loop, the variable x is destroyed, then re-created for the next pass through the loop. However, this seems odd, since I would think it'd be more efficient to keep x "alive" and just re-assign it to the new value on each iteration.

The variable `x` is created only once, but it is not created until after you begin to iterate over `locals()`, because the source iterable of the `for` loop is evaluated before anything is assigned to the loop variable.  The error message, however, is raised by the dict itself (or rather, its iterator): it "notices" when something is trying to iterate it and it has changed since its last iteration.  So what happens is:

1. `locals()` is evaluated and gives you a dict
2. the `for` loop creates an iterator over the dict and gets the first element
3. a new local `x` is created and set to that first element
4. on the next loop iteration, the `for` loop tries to get another element from the dict iterator
5. the dict iterator notices that the underlying dict has a new element (`x`) since the last iteration, so it raises the error.

A simple workaround is to create the variable `x` with some dummy value before the loop.  Then it will already exist before you ever access `locals()`, and there will be no creation of new variables during the loop:

```
def print_args(i,j,k):
    x = None
    for x in locals():
        print(locals()[x])

>>> print_args('a', 'b', 'c')
a
x
c
b
```

Notice, of course, that you will also get `x` itself during this iteration.

As others have mentioned in the comments, it's not really clear why you're doing this at all.  `locals()` is a rather slippery beast and usually, given some practical task you're trying to accomplish, there's a better way to do it without using `locals()`.

Comment: I realize that now, based on what others are saying. I just discovered  `locals()` exists because I was trying to get back the arguments of a function, and it was suggested (...somewhere). I think the best mentioned solution is using `function(*i)`, which seems a lot better given that I'd only get the arguments, and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `for x in locals()`, `locals()` is evaluated then its first item is stored in `x`. `x` wasn't defined before, hence it is being added to the `locals` dictionary during the first loop and the second loop notices the change.

One way of workarounding this is to copy the `locals` dictionary beforehand as you've mentioned:

```
def print_args(i,j,k):
    local_args = dict(locals())
    for x in local_args:
        print(local_args[x])

print_args('a','b','c')
```